# Named query with optional parameter not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

I have a named query below for optional parameter which is flightNumber, departureAirport  and arrivalAirport. But this query is not working when I don't give any value for these parameter.

```
@Query("from CapacityMonitor
  where carrierCode = :carrierCode and
  (:flightNumber IS NULL OR flightNumber = :flightNumber) and 
  (:departureAirport IS NULL OR departureAirport = :departureAirport) and
  (:arrivalAirport IS NULL OR arrivalAirport = :arrivalAirport)
```

I can change a query but i have to use with @Query annotation only

Comment: `IS NULL` won't save you from not giving any value :)

Comment: but in other posts this is the solution they have provided for optional parameters.

Comment: Of course it is 50% of the solution but you have to set the parameter to `null`. That works under the basis that `null is null` returns `true`, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: tht means wht i have written the query is correct thn wht m i supposed to do to make it working

Comment: Try to use QueryUpdate instead of NamedQuery, also suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44107678/2877012)

Comment: Try to use CriteriaUpdate insted of NamedQuery [as mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44107678/2877012)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to keep your query the way it is and make it work with or without parameters. Well, you can't do that. If the query is expecting parameters, then you have to set them.

The best approach would be to leave the query the same way it is and set the parameters to `NULL` so that `:param IS NULL` returns `TRUE` in those cases and return all results. That way you will fake a match.

Anyway, the parameter has to be set always.

Comment: thanks mostacho for ur reply but i am keeping it as ":param IS NULL" but that is not working tht's y i m asking

Comment: As I said, `the parameter has to be set always`. Set it to `NULL` to fake a match.

Comment: Thanks, can u tell me how will my query looks like after that, can u help me out in that

Comment: As I said, `leave the query the same way it is`. Then, when you wanted to omit the parameters, instead of omitting them (which is not possible), you should set the parameter to `null`. That way the query would run as if the parameter is not there. Do you get the idea?

Comment: tht means wht i have written the query is correct thn wht m i supposed to do to make it working

Comment: Is your a button broken? Anyway, do something like `SET param := NULL;` before executing your query.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a **Criteria Query** to build a statement with custom `WHERE` clause.

Based on your example, it could look like this (*depending on your data types*):

```
public List<CapacityMonitor> getFlights(String carrierCode, String flightNumber, String departureAirport, String arrivalAirport) {
  CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<CapacityMonitor> query = builder.createQuery(CapacityMonitor.class);

  Root<CapacityMonitor> root = query.from(CapacityMonitor.class);
  query.select(root);

  // Carrier code is mandatory
  query.where(builder.equals(root.get("carrierCode"), carrierCode));

  // Other properties are optional
  if (null != flightNumber && flightNumber.length() > 0) {
    query.where(builder.equals(root.get("flightNumber"), flightNumber));
  }

  // Use LIKE expression to match partially
  if (null != departureAirport && departureAirport.length() > 0) {
    query.where(builder.like(root.get("departureAirport"), "%" + departureAirport + "%"));
  }

  if (null != arrivalAirport && arrivalAirport.length() > 0) {
    query.where(builder.like(root.get("arrivalAirport"), "%" + arrivalAirport + "%"));
  }

  return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```